# How can I set default transparency on CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm on Windows 10, and every time I open a Command Line, I have to readjust the settings I've made, because the default settings don't allow me to change the transparency values.

Apparently,I have to modify regedit files. I researched and I found the next HKEY config:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"WindowAlpha"=dword:000000c8
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"WindowAlpha"=dword:000000c8

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_SysWOW64_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"WindowAlpha"=dword:000000c8
```

But it doesn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong, I would really appreciate some help guys, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are talking about opening a Command Prompt.  I do this a fair bit, and I have the Command Prompt pinned to the Taskbar.  Once I do this, the shortcut on the Taskbar has its own properties, and making changes in the Registry has no effect on it.  This is nice, for me, as I can modify the properties to something that I like, but still open a default Command Prompt by typing "cmd" into the search box.

To do this, open a Command Prompt.  Next, right-click on the Command Prompt icon on the Taskbar, and select the 'Pin to Taskbar' option.  Once done, right-click on the Command Prompt icon again (the one on the Taskbar), and then right-click on the first item ("Command Prompt") and this should open a new list.  Click on Properties in this new list.  You should be able to set the transparency value here: Select the 'Colors' tab, and it's located near the bottom.

When I do this, new sessions of the Command Prompt will start (when launched from the pinned item on the Taskbar) with the desired transparency.  But typing "cmd" into the Search Box launches a Command Prompt with the default values, which includes no transparency (for me).

I also looked at the Registry values you've posted.  I made this single change to my registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console] "WindowAlpha"=dword:000000c8
```

At that point, I launched a Command Prompt by typing "cmd" into the Search Box. 
 The Command Prompt started with the opacity set to 78% (which I believe is the desired effect).  And this had no impact on the Command Prompts I launched by using the icon on my Taskbar.

Comment: `HKCU\Console` has the default settings that you can change in the GUI using the "Defaults" menu item. It gets overridden by subkeys named for the initial console window title. This will be the full executable path with backslashes replaced by underscore, unless the `CreateProcess` `STARTUPINFO` sets a custom `lpTitle`. That's something you can easily do via cmd's `start` command, e.g. `start "Python" python`, for which the console window settings will be saved to `HKCU\Console\Python` for the next time you open a console with "Python" as the window title.

Comment: As you've already experienced, .lnk shortcuts can also store console settings that override the defaults, and when you start a console from a shortcut it remembers to store modified settings back to the shortcut.

Comment: Of course none of this has anything inherently to do with cmd.exe. This is all implemented in the console host process, conhost.exe, which gets started via API calls when a console process is created with a new console window, or when a process calls `AllocConsole` to create a new console. cmd.exe just happens to be the console process people are used to starting first as a work shell for integrating other console programs, but powershell.exe is gaining in popularity, and a lot of programmers prefer bash.exe over Microsoft's shells.

Comment: I have cmd.exe pinned to the taskbar, yet when I edit the transparency, close, & re-open the window, the transparency has returned to 100.

Comment: the registry key worked for me. For some reason it seems to not save itself when I change other settings in the cmd prompt